# R Code for Hyperspectral Indices

Tags: r, multi-band, hyperspectral-sensor

I am planning to use R to read hyperspectral images and calculate hyperspectral indices. There seems to be scripts available online, but mostly for multispectral images. For instance, this code for NDVI uses only two bands:

```
VI <- function(img, k, i) {
          bk <- img[[k]]
          bi <- img[[i]]
          vi <- (bk - bi) / (bk + bi)
          return(vi)
        }

 #knowing the band numbers for k(5) and i(3), the NDVI is:

 ndvi <- VI(hyper_image, 5, 3)
```

My dilemma is: I use a hyperspectral image with 100 bands.  The above code becomes inefficient because I want to use all 100 bands in the formula.

```
#if, for example, these are my 100 bands: k, i, j, n, m, o, p, .... 

#And just for the sake of illustration, this is a sample equation:

vi <- (bk + bi + bj + bn + bm + bo + bp + ....) / (bk + bi + bj + bn + bm + bo + bp + ....)

return(vi)

hyper_index <- VI(hyper_image, 5, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, ...)

#Obviously, doing this is excruciating!
```

Can someone point me to existing R code for this procedure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may consider using the R package [hsdar](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hsdar/index.html) as a starting point to carry out transformation of spectral response data as well calculation of vegetation indices. You will find additional information about this package in [this article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/325142486_Hyperspectral_Data_Analysis_in_R_the_hsdar_Package) published in the Journal of Statistical Software.  While the [hyperSpec](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hyperSpec/index.html) package might also be of use.

This [tutorial](https://www.neonscience.org/hsi-hdf5-r) provides useful information on working with hyperspectral data in R using the hdf5 format.